# How to save a pandas dataframe into a string that i can save and retrieve from a single column in sql database?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called `df` and I want to save it in the database's single column such that I can retrieve it into a dataframe format and used in my functions.

I have found the functions like df.to_string and df._to_sql. I could save it as a string but there is no way I could retrieve the data back into a dataframe.

Any idea how can I do this?

Comment: But I want to save the dataframe in a single database column. Maybe a way  to compress it into a string and convert it back to dataframe?

Comment: It's just how the infrastructure of my system is made. Saving in a single column makes it far more efficient, easy and fast to use it.

Answer (score 3):

So I have found an answer for myself if anyone out there is looking for the same solution. You can use pandas [to_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) and [read_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html) to encode it into JSON and save in the database and then read it back to a variable.

Here is an example:

```
    x = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3, 2),
                     columns=['foo', 'bar'],
                     index=['a', 'b', 'c'])
    x = x.to_json()
    y = pd.read_json(x)
```